# Not able to find Scripting Files Folder / tree in umbraco 7.2.6

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-blog, umbraco-contour

I have download & Install Umbraco 7.2.6 , 
But In Developer section I am not able to view "Scripting Files" tree

[image]

Where in umbraco 7.1.3  can view it.

[image]

So do I need to do any config. Change to make it enable ?

Comment: You mean javascript files or...?

Comment: No, the Scripting Files (Have added the Image)

Comment: Correct, but you can still use Scripted Files in a Macro. (if you upgrade, for new work use partial view (macros))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go and look at the release informations of umbraco, you can see that standard in [Umbraco version 7.2.0](https://our.umbraco.org/contribute/releases/720/) this has been disabled.

**From the release note:**

```
U4-4828 Disable Scripting Files tree and don't ship the macroScripts folder
```

The reason behind this is because `Scripting files` was used for the older razor files. Instead you should use the `partial views` and `partial view macros`.